# Why aren't AoE ranges appearing?

Tags: pillars-of-eternity

I've seen that there are supposed to be red/yellow circles indicating AoE range in Pillars of Eternity, but when I hover to cast a spell, nothing appears.
Are there any graphical options that might cause this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a tickbox in the game options menu where you can toggle this on and off.

[image: Game options menu]

An afterthought; but worth mentioning. As you move the difficulty slider, the checkboxes will update to match.